# Active VBA Macro that performs a vlookup to a separate sheet in the workbook

Tags: vba, vlookup

I was asked to do this specifically not in the sheet itself within the cell.

I need a constantly running Macro so that when I put an ID number in cell D9 in sheet 1, various other cells in Sheet 1 get populated by data points in a table in Sheet 2.

I have the following:

Also, Excel is crashing constantly doing this, but my instruction is specifically to use VBA and not use normal lookups in the cell.

Tried setting it to general and other things. very new to VBA sorry

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byVal Target As Range)
Dim ID As String
Dim LookupRange As Range
Set LookupRange = Sheet3.Range("A13:AN200")
Dim DataValue As String

If Sheets("Template").Range("D9").Value <> "" Then
     ID = Sheets("Template").Range("D9")
     DataValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(ID, LookupRange, 3, False)
     Range("D11").Value = DataValue

End if
End
```

Comment: specifically, the Set LookupRange line is the problem

Comment: "is the problem" - what does this mean? Error message?

Comment: There are several big issues with what you posted. I would recommend you start by learning about the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object. Specifically, you are going to have issues assigning a range to a string variable, and referring to a range that hasn't been specified either in a variable or by its associated sheet (this line - `Range("D11").Value = DataValue`).

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and made some changes that should allow it to work. I have commented most of what I did. If you have questions please let me know.

Disclaimer: This is untested. So you will want to verify it before actually using it.

```vb
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim ws3 As Worksheet
        Dim wsName As String
        Dim IDRange As String
        Dim ResultRange As String
        Dim vLookUpRange As String
        Dim ID As String
        Dim LookupRange As Range
        Dim DataValue As String

        wsName = "Template"

        IDRange = "D9"
        ResultRange = "D11"
        vLookUpRange = "A13:AN200"

        'This is just a habbit of mine, I always set sheets to their own variables.
        'It is just easier for me to work with
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets(3)

        'This line (moved from below Dim) was not writen correctly. it is not Sheet3 but sheets(3) As you can see I moved
        'the sheet definition to above. (Again a habbit of mine)
        Set LookupRange = ws3.Range(vLookUpRange)

        'This is not needed but I add it when I am working with changes to sheets so that I only run the code I want
        'when it is within the rang I am looking for. You could add logic to make sure that you only run the code if
        'you are only modifying that spesific cell. But for your goal, I don't think it is needed.
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range(IDRange)) Is Nothing Then

            'You can use .Value but .Value2 is slightly faster with very few consequences.
            'eg if you ever need to read or write large amounts of data it will save you some time.
            If ws.Range(IDRange).Value2 <> "" Then
                ID = ws.Range(IDRange)
                DataValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, LookupRange, 3, False)
                'You also need to specify a sheet for this. Since this is located in the sheet you are entering
                'data I assumed the sheet "template"
                ws.Range(ResultRange).Value = DataValue
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```